# Wcf Callback in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hello I have a question please,i have application asp.net will connect to service Wcf and this service will notify clients,after notification my application disappear (page disposed),help me please

Answer (score 0):

Use WCF Duplex services:

- http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/48/posts/10054/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Comment: thanks but can you help me for project asp.net, with application windows forms fine but my problem when i have callback wcf with asp.net